# imshow basemap doesn't fit in to a map

Tags: python, interpolation, matplotlib-basemap, imshow

I am very new on python. I need to plot the CO2 map over European domain using netcdf files from daily global cams dataset.

1-I can plot global domain correctly without any interpolations. However, using imshow command to interpolate the map is upside down. I worked around the problem setting the -1 on latitude as you can see on code below. CO2[i,0,::-1,:].[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcAen.jpg)

The simply code is :
    #data read 
    data = Dataset (r'D:\Users\\cams_2018.nc')

```
CO2=data.variables['CO2'][:]
#global projection
mp = Basemap(projection='robin',lon_0=0,lat_0=0,resolution='i')

#european projection

#mp = Basemap(projection='merc',
#       llcrnrlat=20,        #lower left corner lon 
#       llcrnrlon=-20,       #lower left conrner lat 
#       urcrnrlat=70,        #uper righ corner lat
#       urcrnrlon=50,        #uper right corner lon
#       resolution='i')      

#Plot map imshow interpolation
c_scheme= mp.imshow(np.squeeze(CO2[i,0,::-1,:]), cmap='seismic', interpolation = 'lanczos')
mp.drawcoastlines()
cbar = mp.colorbar(c_scheme,location='bottom',size="5%",pad="10%", extend='both') #creates a colourbar
```

2-I can graph European domain correctly only without interpolation [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH2oh.jpg)
in fact using imshow command, the plot is completely wrong, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu3T1.jpg)
The CO2 distribution over the European domain, still followed the global distributions, you can distingisc the African and American distribution over Europe.

Does somebody know how can I plot the data over Europe?